# Class 'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' not found in Laravel 5.4 notification

Tags: php, laravel-5, notifications

I need help to resolve an issue with the notification system.

**Here is my notification class:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class ApplicationReceived extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;


    private $testCode;
    private $recipientName;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($testCode='',$name='')
    {
        $this->testCode=$testCode;
        $this->recipientName=$name;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting("Dear ".$this->recipientName)
                ->subject('Your Application Received for The Entrepreneur')
                ->line("Your application to participate in The Entrepreneur project has been received by us")
                ->line("Follow the link below to take a test to complete your application")
                ->action('Take Test', url('/taketest/'.$this->testCode))
                ->line('Thank you for your interest in The Entrepreneur project!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
      }
}
```

**And this is where I call it:**

```
//Notify the candidate
$candidate->notify(new ApplicationReceived($candidate->testcode, $candidate->othernames));
return redirect('/signup')->with('msg', "<div class='alert alert-success'><strong>Your registration information was successfully submitted!</strong><br /> Please check your email for a link to take a test to complete your enrollment!!!</div>");
```

When the application runs, it sends the notification but then throws up the following fatal error message

> FatalErrorException in Mailer.php line 470:
>     Class 'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' not found

[image: the error displayed]

I will appreciate any help to point out where I am going wrong here.

Comment: try to rerun `composer update` and/or run`composer dump-autoload` please, MessageSent was added in the last version (5.4.18) 4 days ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @dparoli for your suggestion.

However, I tried both `composer dumpautoload` and `composer update` all to no avail.

Actually, what I did that solved the problem is very close to what you suggested. After creating a new laravel project, I realized that it contains the missing file (MessageSent.php) in the same location as MessageSending.php.

**So, I just copied the file (MessageSent.php) to the same in  my own project and it worked.**

Thank you for your efforts and pointing me in the right direction.

I really hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

The class `Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent` was added only in the last version of laravel (5.4.18), so you can proceed this way:

Run `composer update` just in the case the last run was gone wrong.

If the error is still there IMHO it could be a permissions issue so there are two cases:

1) you run `composer update` with a user that has not writing permissions in the vendor directory, so you have to use another user (see case 2)

2) you run `composer update` with **root** and you forgot to `chown` the laravel directory to the web server user/group, i.e.:

```
chmod -R nginx:nginx /path/to/laraveldir
```

Sobstitute `nginx:nginx` with your webserver `user:group`.

In either case a **stop** and **start** to the webserver service could also help.